# Web 8 staging deployer issue

Tags: publishing, web8, cdaas

I have live and staging services installed on the same server (CDaaS).  If I publish a Page to both live and staging I get a success message in the queue.  In the database I see the page in live (broker_live) but not in staging (broker).  I tried to restart the staging services but I get the same result.  If I restart the server then try again the publish works for staging; however, after a short while I face the same situation again.

My discovery and preview services seem fine, I can navigate to them in the browser.

Services:
Live Discovery
  Live Deployer
  Content
  Live Context
Staging Discovery
  Staging Deployer
  Preview
  Staging Context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On further investigation I noticed that I hadn't provided different directories for the deployer's queue.  If implementing two deployers on the same machine, in my case one for Staging and one for Live, then each must have its own queue directories.

Open the Live Deployer's config/**cd_deployer_conf.xml** and change the following:

[image]

In my environment I left all Staging services with default configuration settings and appended 'live' to all my Live configurations.